# JNI how to release it

Tags: java-native-interface

I'm a JNI navice, a issue about release memory has blocked me, the scenario like below:
     If you have convert a ArrayList from Java to C, and put the ArrayList elements from  String array like:

```
 jclass arrlist_cls = (*env)->FindClass(env,"java/util/ArrayList");
 if(NULL==arrlist_cls)return;
 jmethodID m_get = (*env)->GetMethodID(env,arrlist_cls,"get","(I)Ljava/lang/Object");
 jmethodID m_size = (*env)->GetMethodID(env,arrlist_cls,"size","()I");

 //get the ArrayList field from object
 jfieldID fidArrStr = (*env)->GetFieldID(env,helloObj,"arrStr",
   "Ljava/util/ArrayList;");
 jobject ArrObj = (*env)->GetObjectField(env,paramsObj,fidArrStr);
 if(NULL==ArrObj)return;
 int len = (*env)->CallIntMethod(env,ArrObj,size_method);
 int i=0; const char **ArrStr;
 for(i=0;i<len;i++){
     jstring jstr = (jstring)(*env)->CallObjectMethod(env,ArrObj,get_method,i);
     ArrStr[i]=jstr;
 }
```

How can i release it like single String?you know, the single String could use the method of **ReleaseStringUTFChars** to release, 
how can i release a array object memory? Because String is not primitive type, so i can't find  **ReleaseArrayElements** method to use.

Comment: Your question doesn't appear to have anything to do with JNI. There is no 'array object memory' here. You appear to be looking for the `free()` function; otherwise not a real question.

Comment: Please show more of your code. It is unclear what is assigned to `strArr`.

Comment: Hi, i add some code and detail process of this issue, could you have a look ? :-)

Comment: Generally it doesn't get released, it just escapes.  (What?  Oh, I thought you were talking about the application.)

Comment: Look at what? What are you asking about? `ArrObj`? `ArrStr`? What's the question here?

Comment: i mean how to release the ArrStr..that's my point...

Answer (score 1):

> I mean how to release the ArrStr.

This code won't even work: it will get a `SIGSEGV` when you execute `ArrStr[i] = ...` So I don't know why you're worrying about termination yet.

You need to *allocate* `ArrStr` before you can use it. How you allocate it determines how you release it. If you allocate it with `new` you must release it with `delete`. If you allocate it as an array, i.e. `char *ArrStr[len]`, it will disappear when the method exits: no release required.

If you're asking about how to deallocate the `jstrings` returned by `CallObjectMethod()`, again they are released automatically by JNI when you exit this JNI method. You can release them explicitly prior to that, if necessary, with [`DeleteLocalRef()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#DeleteLocalRef).

Comment: very thanks your answer, i'm not very familiar with C language. i define a array in C, `const char **arrStr` , but this array length depends on the Java's ArrayList object. So I'm not sure this array should be allocated memory in compile time. From the JNI API, i saw the jstring and some other Array object has API that could help to release, so i think `ArrStr` also need to be release.

Comment: `const char **ArrStr` is not an array. It is a pointer to pointer. If you want it to point to something you have to arrange that, e.g. `= calloc(len, sizeof char*);` and then `free()` it afterwards. It is a C object, nothing to do with the JNI API whatsoever.

Comment: So you think, i only need to release it use **free()**?

Comment: David, I don't know why you're asking me to repeat myself. You need to re-read what I've written. I've just said exactly that, and I've also said other things that bear significantly on this problem.